# Out-of-practice pianist wants suggestions for getting back into it

Tags: piano, repertoire

So long story short I was an active concert pianist who had to give it up due to repetitive strain injuries in the wrists/forearms. I took up a PhD in a fall-back field and I feel like my injuries are manageable as they now have minimal impact on my day-to-day life.

I'm looking for repertoire suggestions to ease back into regular playing. It's so easy to fall back onto extraordinarily "academic" repertoire or convince myself that playing through Chopin Op 10 isn't a bad idea, but I want to do this right and enjoy myself doing it while not overburdening my wrists and elbows.

So - does anyone have suggestions for enjoyable (but also non-trivial) repertoire?

Comment: Hire a teacher who is able and willing to work with you on your particular situation

Comment: @ToddWilcox that is in fact a good idea but living on a grad student stipend completely prohibits me from hiring a teacher

Comment: @JarradPerron you might consider barter.  I've had a couple of students over the years who swapped professional services for lessons.  It might be harder to find someone willing to accept whatever it is you have to offer instead of money, but it's probably worth trying.

Comment: I left some suggestions in [the chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/58894761#58894761).

Comment: Your practice regime should be influenced by what exactly your ambitions are in regards to your playing

Comment: I'm assuming the OP is American, but you can get quality music education for around 30 - 50 $ per hour lesson. This could be equal to eating take-out meals one time a week less

Comment: @JarradPerron I'm going to second the recommendation of professional help, but not so much for repertoire as for posture and technique. Especially with a prior injury, you should make sure you're not going to re-injure yourself. Maybe a physical therapist who specializes in music.

Comment: @Aaron your advice was by far the most helpful thank you muchly

Answer (score 1):

Firstly I must endorse Todd Wilcox' idea that you should find a teacher.  That would be the your best move here.

But if that is really out of the question then surely the sort of thing that you are looking for are pieces by some of the great masters that are stylisticly difficult but technically easier.

For example Mozarts sonatas, much early Beethoven, much of J.S. Bach.  Not as technically demanding as late romantic or many modern pieces but extremely satisfying to play and requiring considerable effort to play in the correct style.

I could make a list but as someone with experience who has already got to a high level of playing I expect that you can identify the sort of pieces fairly I mean easily by yourself.

Godd luck.

Answer (score -2):

There is no such thing as repetitive strain, only improper movement which makes all movement repetitive strain.  I suggest you contact Edna Golandsky in NYC and relearn how to move properly.

I was paralyzed with bilateral tendonitis pain for two years and sought relief from multiple doctors to no avail.  It was the teaching of Dorothy Taubman (deceased) which has had me pain free for the past 20 years.  The problem with re-learning how to move is that the improper movements are permanently hardwired into our brains (muscle memory) forever.  They can be overwritten but are always laying in wait to resurface and wreak havoc. If you have been taught to brow-beat technique into your fingers, which have no muscle, through strength and endurance, then learn to move properly according to the laws of physics, and then the improper movement resurfaces, you can injure yourself all over again and rather quickly because the improper "strength and endurance" quickly atrophies.  That is why missing a few days of practice can make us feel rusty.  The body is purging what it knows it doesn't need.  Old technique can resurface when we are nervous or cold.  I just played a recital which I could execute flawlessly and at great speed but I was nervous and could feel the old movements trying to creep back in and was giving me the "twisties."  I could sense the downward spiral but I was about 75% successful at maintaining proper movement by focusing on gravity, rotation and in/out movement. I give myself a C- and hopefully the next time I can raise that to a C+.